# NullPointerException while calling static method of static subclass

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception, static-methods

```java
class A {
    public static class B {
        private static String[] names;
        public static void addName(int i, String name) {
            names[i] = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `A.B.addName(0,"test");` causes NullPointerException. I'm new to Java, so could anyone explain why? I wanted to fill the names array on the beginning of the app and make all instances of A use the same data.

Comment: If you are new to Java, I wouldn't recommend inner class (or static classes and variables), unless you know why you need them

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not new to programming, so I know why I need them, it's just the thing that I have never done anything with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the array with some size, otherwise it is null.

```
private static String[] Names = new String[5];
```